# Google maps not loading in ionic3

Tags: google-maps, ionic3

I am trying to load Google maps in ionic apps using below code but nothing happens when i run my code (map is not loading and no exception also showing in console) I Enabled **Maps for Android and Ios** in Google console and get API key following some tutorials

.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="height: 100%;" id="map_canvas"></div> 
</ion-content>
```

.ts:

```
  map:GoogleMap;
  lat:any; lang:any;
  constructor() {
    this.loadGoogleMap();
  }  
  loadGoogleMap(){
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);    
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        this.map.addMarker({
            title: 'Ionic',
            icon: 'blue',
            animation: 'DROP',
            position: {
              lat: 43.0741904,
              lng: -89.3809802
            }
          })
          .then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => {

              });
          });

      });
  }
```

Comment: Sometimes it can be div issue use this                                                                    let mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
this.map = GoogleMaps.create(mapDiv, mapOptions);

Comment: Fiza Khan no user even i paste your code\

Comment: Your are calling the function in constructor call it once the platform is ready i.e in ionViewDidLoad() and if it does not work than add timer of 5s in ionViewDidLoad like this ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.loadGoogleMap();
    }, 5000);
    
  }